# Juntar 2 if's Php

Tags: php

é possivel eu juntar dois if's quase seguidos?

```
    ' <p>Trabalhador (4) Validade:';
  if ($exibe['MedicaValidade4'] != '0000-00-00')
 {
  if (strtotime($exibe['MedicaValidade4']) < time()) 
   {
    echo '<span style="color:red">'.$exibe['MedicaValidade4'].'</span>';
    echo '<a href="MostrarMedica4.php?id='. $exibe['id'].'">&nbsp; Ver PDF</a>';
  } else {
    echo $exibe['MedicaValidade4'];
    echo '<a href="MostrarMedica4.php?id='.$exibe['id'].'">&nbsp; Ver PDF</a></p>';
  }
}





<p><b>Projectista: </b></p>
       <p>Projectista Numero: '.$exibe["ProjectistaNumero"].'</p>
       <p>Projectista Validade:';
```

Isto tudo dentro de PHP

O que quero fazer é ver se a data Medicavalidade esta preechida e verificar se a data passa o dia de hoje. Se passar fica os numeros a vermelho.
Se não fica os numeros a preto. 
Se não houver dados preenchidos não mostra nada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não entendi muito bem sua pergunta. Mas pelo que eu entendi vou tentar fazer, caso estiver errado, edite sua pergunta adicionando mais detalhes.

Você vai criar um if para saber se a data estiver preenchida, e dentro desse if verificar se a data já passou. Simples, um if/else dentro de um if. Deve ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
if($exibe['MedicaValidade'] != NULL) { //Verifica se o número foi preenchido.
     $diaAtual = date("Y-m-d"); // Recebe o dia atual.
     if($exibe['MedicaValidade'] > $diaAtual) { // Compara, caso o dia recebido seja maior que o dia atual...
           echo "O Dia ja passou. Faça aqui a mudança da cor.";
     } else { Se não...
            echo "O dia ainda não passou.";
} else { // E caso a data não esteja preenchida.
        echo "Preencha a data!";
}
```

Bem, não testei o código, mas acho que dá pra ter um norte. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: estou com dificuldade por causa das clicas. vou alterar a minha pergunta a ver se me consegues ajudar

Answer (score 0):

Não há motivos Pra juntar ter dois If, como você fez. Você poderia ter usado o operador `&&` pra juntar as expressões condicionais

Assim

`If ($condicao_1 == true && $condicao_2 == true)`

Ou seja, acima você está dizendo que a primeira e a segunda condição devem ser verdadeiras